# Are there alternatives to paid HDD data recovery on a semi-dead drive that actually work?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I need a file from a WD caviar 80 GB SATA hard drive.  It doesn't show up in my computer. It's in disk management but you can't assign a drive letter.  It says cyclic errors so i tried chkdsk but the partition that has all the stuff on is not there.  It's a 80 GB capacity but it says on diskpart that there are no partitions and the capacity of the drive is only 5.7 GB the other 70 GB has dissapeared.

I tried a few recovery programs but they can't see the lost partition either and think its only a 5.7 GB drive. I think the original problem occured when the computer was unexpectedly cut off from the power.

Any suggestions to recover my lost file?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum your partition table is fried.  Many recovery programs can't touch that.

I have had success in the past with: http://www.r-studio.com/

Last I knew there was a free version that let you do everything except actually recover files over some small size limit--you could try it and see if it finds your stuff without paying.

Beware that there seems to be an unrelated www.rstudio.com that I know nothing about but the similarity of the names strongly suggests they aren't honest.

Comment: Hi, good suggestion but i've already used r-studio and it would only scan within the 5.7gb volume it "saw". There doesn't seem to be an option to scan the whole drive unfortunately. The visible part of the drive is empty with no recoverable files.

Comment: @Skxawng Unfortunately your probably looking at hardware failure in that case.  That makes it a job for the pros.